# Is there a way a task could iterate over measurements and aggregate data into another bucket?

Tags: influxdb, flux, influxdb-2

I’m using a bucket for collecting tick data for multiple symbols in Binance (e.g. ETH/BTC and BNB/BTC) and storing on different measurements (binance_ethbtc and binance_bnbbtc respectively) and that’s working fine. Other than that, I’d like to make aggregations of OHLC data into another bucket, just like [this guy here](https://community.influxdata.com/t/advice-on-aggregating-to-ohlc-data/13303). I’ve already managed to write Flux code for aggregating this data for a single measurement but then it got me wondering: **do I need to write a task for EVERY measurement I have? Isn’t there a way of iterating over measurements in a bucket and aggregating the data into another one?**

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to FixTestRepeat on the InfluxDB community, I've managed to do it (and iterating over measurements is not necessary). He's showed me that if I remove the filter for the `_measurement` field, the query will yield as many series as there are measurements. More information [here](https://community.influxdata.com/t/is-there-a-way-a-task-could-iterate-over-measurements-and-aggregate-data-into-another-bucket/18746)